# Custom Positioning of H3 and P

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My HTML is like this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Content</p>

    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Content</p>

    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Problem Nr. 1 I can't change the HTML.
I want that p is Boxed(no problem) but than I want that they are in a row.
`display: flex;` was my option.
When I use flex `h3` and `p` are next to each other.
But I want that `h3` is above `p`.

Desired output example:

```
h3_________h3_________h3
p__________p__________p
```

How can I align them?

sorry for my english not my native language

Comment: Add working demo in snippet

Comment: thanks so mutch to all of you :) helped me alot understanding flex better now :)

Answer (score 1):

Attempt with flexbox, since you cant change the HTML, setting a 33% width shouldn't be an issue:

```css
div {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
}
div > h3,
div > p {
  width: 33.333%;
}
div > h3 {
  order: 1;
}
div > p {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Title1</h3>
  <p>Content1</p>

  <h3>Title2</h3>
  <p>Content2</p>

  <h3>Title3</h3>
  <p>Content3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: as i said i can not change the HTML so only one Div contain all content

Comment: @Max Lang If you can not change html the only way is to use js DOM.

Comment: well ok :) thought i could skip this ...xD thx a lot to u guys :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{ flex-flow: row wrap;display: flex; }
.test h3,.test p { width: 33.333%;}
.test h3 {order: 1;}
.test p {order: 2;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h3>Title1</h3>
  <p>content1</p>
  <h3>Title2</h3>
  <p>content2</p>
  <h3>Title3</h3>
  <p>content3</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: no thats not what i want. content 1,2,3 shuld be under Title 1,2,3

Comment: @ Max Lang now chek it.

Comment: well i have this. i know this. but what i want is, that title 1 content 1 is right under eachother and the following next to them

Comment: @MaxLang now check it.

Answer (score 0):

Create new external div and set property.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

My example:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```